# How we can disable the magnification glass in uiwebview in ios 9 - Swift

Tags: css, xcode, swift, ios9

How we can disable the **magnification glass** in **uiwebview** in **ios 9** ?

I use this code below to disable the selection/copy.. in uiwebview:

```
* {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
     -webkit-user-select: none; /* Disable selection/copy in UIWebView */
}
```

it works, but the problem is the **new magnification glass** in ios 9, so is there any solution to **disable** it?
Note: I don't use Cordova

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just tried the following hack & it worked for me.
This will override the long press in the webView.

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:nil action:NULL];
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.2;
[webView addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

**Swift**

```
 let longPress:UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: nil, action: nil)
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.2
    webView.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
```

Comment: If you do this, Yes magnification glass will be disable. However, generic way to hold and select `UIWebView` will not work. For example, you can't use `Cut`, `Paste`, `Copy` or `Select All` since you can't select text.

Comment: That's is the reason why I want to disable the magnification glass

Comment: I see. My problem was removable of empty magnification glass.

Comment: not sure how can we achieve this without hacking some private APIs, furthermore this solution does not work with WKWebview

Answer (score 0):

I also found this problem in my app built with XCode 6.3.1.
But after I built my app with XCode 7, UIWebView's behavior about magnifying glass changed as below.

1. UIWebView for file previewing does not show magnifying glass on long tapping.
2. UIWebView for web browsing show magnifying glass on long tapping.

I think this is a problem of XCode 6 and iOS 9

If there's no problem using XCode 7,
Use XCode 7 to build your app, the problem will be solved.